# Convert text file to JSON in Java

Tags: java, json

How do I convert a text file to Json file?
I have a raw in.txt file as below:

```
{“person”:{“name”:”AAAA”,”sid”:09328,”location”:”Sao Paulo”}}
{“person”:{“name”:”BBBBB”,”sid”:01934,”location”:”Brasilia”}}
```

A little help is much appreciated !

Comment: do you mean "a text file to a json OBJECT"?

Comment: Yes, a text file to json object. actually i m new to java and learning json as well

Comment: Just as a side note: Your text file does not contain a valid JSON object. First, it uses typographic quotes instead of normal double quotes. Second, each line contains a separate JSON object which is at least unusual.

Comment: Please adjust your question and check out json.org for the JSON format.

Answer (score 4):

To convert text file in JSON you can use JACKSON OBJECT MAPPER jar in your code.

Create a simple Employee pojo. We will read JSON string from a file and map it to Employee class.

Here is Code:

```
public class Employee {

private int empId;
private String name;
private String designation;
private String department;
private int salary;

public String toString(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("************************************");
    sb.append("\nempId: ").append(empId);
    sb.append("\nname: ").append(name);
    sb.append("\ndesignation: ").append(designation);
    sb.append("\ndepartment: ").append(department);
    sb.append("\nsalary: ").append(salary);
    sb.append("\n************************************");
    return sb.toString();
}

public int getEmpId() {
    return empId;
}
public void setEmpId(int empId) {
    this.empId = empId;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getDesignation() {
    return designation;
}
public void setDesignation(String designation) {
    this.designation = designation;
}
public String getDepartment() {
    return department;
}
public void setDepartment(String department) {
    this.department = department;
}
public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
public void setSalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
```

}

After THIS POJO CLASS 
**Finally here is the example to convert JSON string value to java object**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException; 
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper; 
import com.java2novice.json.models.Employee;

public class JsonToObject {

public static void main(String a[]){

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        File jsonInputFile = new File("C:\\jsonInput.txt");
        Employee emp = mapper.readValue(jsonInputFile, Employee.class);
        System.out.println(emp);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

AND here Is your JSON file:
**jsonInput.txt file contains below json input:**

```
 {
"empId": 1017,
"name": "Nagesh Y",
"designation": "Manager",
"department": "Java2Novice",
"salary": 30000
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to download a JSON library for Java. Go to [this page](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) then click on "Free source code is available." That will lead you to a GitHub page, click on Downloads, download the entire library, extract it, copy the whole extracted folder to your project's source folder, and include it as a source in your project. In Eclipse, that would be right-click on project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path... --> Java Build Path and under the Source tab, click "Add folder" and point to the extracted folder.

You can then start reading your file line by line and simply pass each one to the constructor of a new `JSONObject`. For example:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(...);
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(line);
    ...
    ...
}
```

I'd like to reiterate Codo's comment, though. You're using typographic quotes (`”`, slanted) instead of actual double quotes (`"`, straight), so you might want to `replace()` every occurrence of that before proceeding. Also, `trim()` the line before passing it on to `JSONObject`, just to get rid of any trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

use [this](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) api and then :

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject o = (JsonObject)parser.parse(one_by_one_line_from_text_file);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your text file already contains valid JSON.

If your goal is to obtain a JSON Object, you are probably looking for [this](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29) function.

Comment: The link leads to 404 page.